# Selector bulk action missing

Tags: media

In the media library, I should see a dropdown selector that allows me to delete bulk items. Is there a way to turn this off and on? I've inherited this site and I'm not sure if the original owner has turned this option off somewhere.

Here is the code that should appear:

```html
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-header" id="edit-header" class="js-form-wrapper form-wrapper"><div data-drupal-selector="edit-media-bulk-form" id="edit-media-bulk-form--2" class="js-form-wrapper form-wrapper"><div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-action form-item-action">
        <label for="edit-action">Action</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-action" id="edit-action" name="action" class="form-select">
          <option value="media_delete_action">Delete media</option>
          <option value="media_publish_action">Publish media</option>
          <option value="media_save_action">Save media</option>
          <option value="media_unpublish_action">Unpublish media</option>
       </select>
</div>

<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions--2">

  <input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" 
      id="edit-submit--2" name="op" 
      value="Apply to selected items" 
      class="button js-form-submit form-submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution.

I needed to go to Views/Media and add Bulk update to the Fields, but it was missing. Once I realised that I needed to restore it I found this drush command.

```
* drush cim --yes --partial --source=core/modules/media/config/optional && cr
```

Which updates the following:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
| Collection | Config                               | Operation |
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
|            | system.action.media_delete_action    | Create    |
|            | system.action.media_publish_action   | Create    |
|            | system.action.media_save_action      | Create    |
|            | system.action.media_unpublish_action | Create    |
|            | views.view.media                     | Update    |
+------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Then clear cache and Bulk update has now been restored to the Fields section.